Cessna 172 Nose wheel steering
The POH states that ground steering is done by a spring loaded bungee system. How exactly does depressing the rudders apply pressure to the system to actually turn the wheel? Thanks

Although for a different model of Cessna, this image probably illustrates it as well as can be. There may be some differences with a C172 as described below.

Essentially, rods (4) are mechanically connected to the rudder pedals. These move a crank (3), which in turn operate a spring loaded arm and damper combined (2) which moves the nose wheel.
When stationary the pedals can move, and operate the rudder without the need to overcome resistance and move the wheel. However, during forward movement on the ground, the resistance is reduced allowing the nose wheel to turn.
The C172 differs slightly, the rods are spring loaded instead.

The method of operation is also described in the maintenance manual, which you can find examples of online:

The steerable nose wheel mounted on an air-oil shock strut comprises the nose gear. The shock strut is secured to forgings riveted and/or bolted to the firewall and lower fuselage structure. Nose wheel steering is afforded by two spring-loaded push-pull rods from the rudder pedal bars. A hydraulic fluid-filled shimmy dampener is provided to minimize nose wheel shimmy.

